# Group by names in country in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot

I have a table that have the following fields:

```
id, country_id, name, n_ocurrences
1   uk          John     3
2   us          John     4
3   uk          Matt     0
4   us          Matt     5
```

How would I go to get a list of results that would look like this:

```
name   uk    us   total_ocurrences
John   3     4            7
Matt   0     5            5
```

Right now I am doing this in straight PHP processing the results, but I was wondering if I could do this in MySQL.

**EDIT**: Notice that the table is bigger than this, and actually I am doing a WHERE with a list of country_ids.

Thanks

Comment: Where the list of countries is unknown, you can use a combination of prepared statements and sprocs to do this but frankly it's easier to just do a simple GROUP BY and handle the display at the application level.

Comment: A group by would give just one row for each s_name...And I would lose the values for each country, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of data transformation is a *pivot*. In MySQL to produce this result, you will use an aggregate function with a `case` expression:

```
select name,
  sum(case when country_id = 'uk' then n_ocurrences else 0 end) occurrences_uk,
  sum(case when country_id = 'us' then n_ocurrences else 0 end) occurrences_us,
  sum(n_ocurrences) total_ocurrences
from yourtable
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea26f/2).

The above version works great if you know the values of `country_id` ahead of time, but if you don't then you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic sql:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when country_id = ''',
      country_id,
      ''' then n_ocurrences end) AS occurrences_',
      country_id
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yourtable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', @sql, ' ,
                      sum(n_ocurrences) total_ocurrences
                  FROM yourtable 
                  GROUP BY name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea26f/4)

Both give the result:

```
| NAME | OCCURRENCES_UK | OCCURRENCES_US | TOTAL_OCURRENCES |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| John |              3 |              4 |                7 |
| Matt |              0 |              5 |                5 |
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I should have said that that content of the table was just an example. I have more countries and I don't know which ones I want to do the where with, so I can't "hardcode" country_id = 'uk'. Sorry. I have edited my question.

Comment: @HommerSmith I was working on a dynamic version using a prepared statement when you edited your question.  See my additional query.

Comment: This would work great. However I am not able to do prepared statements in the framework I am working on.  Would it be an easier way to do so?

Comment: There is not if you need to do this dynamically.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have a question in the static version why do we need a case when? Shouldn't a simple IF do the trick?

Comment: @HommerSmith you can use `if`, I use `case` because that it not database specific and can be used on all systems. :)